# Compare values via XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

On the following xml example, I need to compare data products whose minimum stock is higher than its current stock. How can i do it? I don't find any documentation.

```
<products>
<product>
    <cod_prod>1010</cod_prod>
    <name>MSI G41M-P26</name>
    <price>50</price>
    <current_stock>10</current_stock>
    <minimum_stock>3</minimum_stock>
    <cod_zone>10</cod_zone>
</product>
<product>
    <cod_prod>1011</cod_prod>
    <name>Micro Intel Core i5-2320</name>
    <price>120</price>
    <current_stock>3</current_stock>
    <minimum_stock>5</minimum_stock>
    <cod_zone>10</cod_zone>
</product>
<product>
    <cod_prod>1012</cod_prod>
    <name>Micro Intel Core i5 2500</name>
    <price>170</price>
    <current_stock>5</current_stock>
    <minimum_stock>6</minimum_stock>
    <cod_zone>20</cod_zone>
</product>
```

I try with this, but not works:

> /products/product[minimum_stock>/products/product/current_stock]

Comment: Do you need XPath solution only? It can actually easily be done using programming language like C# or any other.

Comment: Yes, i need XPath solution.

Comment: If these values must be in the same node, please try `/products/product[minimum_stock>current_stock]`

Comment: Thank you Uwe Allner, solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XPath is simpler than what you have tried :

```
/products/product[minimum_stock > current_stock]
```

Since context element inside the predicate (`[]`) is the current `product` element, you can simply say `current_stock` instead of `/products/product/current_stock` to reference `current_stock` element of current `product`, just like you already did for `minimum_stock`.

Comment: You might find this compares the values as strings, in which case try `/products/product[ xs:integer(minimum_stock) > xs:integer(current_stock) ] `

Answer (score 0):

```
//product[number(minimum_stock)>number(current_stock)]
```

If you don't use the `number()` function, only strings are compared (the first character of both strings)

Comment: It should be noted that this is not the case in XPath 1.0. From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#booleans): "_When neither object to be compared is a node-set and the operator is <=, <, >= or >, then the objects are compared by converting both objects to numbers and comparing the numbers according to IEEE 754._"